# Python getting a variable in a class

Tags: python, oop, methods

I'm learning right now a python language but I would like to programm in OOP style. Sorry for my questions but in my book and a video tutorial I couldn't find an answer. I know there is easer way to get a number without a method... but I would like to do it in a class ;)

I would like to read a number from a user.

How to write a method that take a number from a user and put it back to a constructor?

I tried this one but it isn't good :(

```
 class example:
      def __init__(self, number):
          self.number = number

      def read(self, a):
           self.a = float(input('Give me a number) '))
           return a


 exampleNumber = example (read())
```

Comment: Why are you passing `a` to `read`?

Comment: I feel like you don't understand what the purpose of a class is, because nothing here makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the concern of storing your number from reading it in from command line. I assume you have something else to achieve with your example class.

```
def read():
    a = float(input('Give me a number: '))
    return a

class Example:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number = number

exampleNumber = Example(read())

print 'The number is %i' % exampleNumber.number
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested separating the input to a standalone function would be a good way to go, but if you really want to keep the input in the class you can use a `classmethod` to provide an alternate constructor:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        a = float(input('Give me a number: '))
        return cls(a)

exampleNumber = Example.from_input()
print("The number is %i" % exampleNumber.number)
```

This is often considered the most Pythonic way to provide multiple constructors for a class with different incompatible parameters. Compare for example `dict.fromkeys(...)`

BTW, the `print` in your code implies you are using Python 2.x. If so you should use `raw_input()` to read values, or better upgrade to Python 3.x.

Comment: I would give +1 for respective: example -> Example (style point) +1, @classmethod +1, explanation for classmethod +1, `from_input` (convention used -> style point)+1 ; but sadly im allowed only one vote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First you initialize the instance ("make me a new `example`!")

```
ex = example()
```

Then you can use its methods:

```
exampleNumber = ex.read()
```

You don't need to pass `a` as an argument, since it will be stored in the instance. Just do something like this:

```
def read(self):
   self.a = float(input('Give me a number) '))
   return self.a
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways , here. 
But, primitively, read the no. outside the class as`

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

num = float(input())
exam = Example(num)
```

and you'd like to define get, edit,etc methods within the class

or perhaps instead of passing the number in the constructor, you can call input() immediately within constructor as:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.number = float(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Gee, boy ... i do not even know where to start.

First DO NOT start with OOP! OOP is in more cases then not understood completely false. It almost always evolves around "abstractions" and "class hierarchies". It does not help that even the "ISO" got it wrong (ISO/IEC 2382-15). (See Alan Kays remarks on this issue, who coined the term object oriented.)

Jack Diederich gave a fantastic talk about OOP and class hysteria at [PyCon US 2012](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes).

But for the sake of your question let us dissect what you got:

```
class example:
```

introduces an object of the type `classobj`, or `type` (depending on the Python version) in the current namespace. And `example` is already an object of it's own and not a 'pure' class in the classic "blueprint" sense, but more like a prototype. You could operate on and with the class, without to instantiate an object from it.

Next:

```
def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number
```

`__init__` is often called a constructor, because it is (almost) the closest thing to it, but still it is not a constructor in a "classical" sense. It does not "create" the object/instance, but merely initializes it. To do it, the method needs to know **which** instance of the many `example` instances it should work with. Therefore every method, which works on instances gets an implicit first argument, called `self` by convention, which holds a reference to the instance, which is you want to work with. If you call `someobj.some_method("some argument")` it gets implicitly translated to something like:

```
class.some_method(someobj, "some argument")  # someobj -> self
```

That is a somewhat crude oversimplification, but it explains the method-signature as defined in the class-declaration.

So if you refer to an attribute of an instance you do it by putting a `self.` as in `self.number` before the specific instance attribute (`number`). You could name it like you want, but you should keep to convention and name it `self`. `self` is like `this` in other languages.

Let us jump ahead to:

```
exampleNumber = example (read())
```

You create an identifier (not a variable, python has no classical variables!) named `exampleNumber` and assign a new object of the type `example` to it and ... huuh? Where does
`read` come from? It's not a python built-in nor is it a keyword. Do you mean the method `read` from the class `example?`? Do you really try to drive in a car, which is not yet build? And on top of that you would need to call it `example.read("some argument here")` or `exampleNumber.read("some bogus Argument here")`.

First things first:

1. instantiate and initialize your object:

   exampleNumber = example(1)
2. then you can operate on it:

   whatever = example.Number.read("curius argument")

And finally lets go over the read method:

```
  def read(self, a):
       self.a = float(input('Give me a number) '))
       return a
```

You probably want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. And you probably also want to return the object attribute a: `self.a`, and not the parameter-value `a`.

I hope i could help you somewhat, but i would strongly suggest to drop the whole OOP notion and start with structured programming. You still will use objects, because in python everything is an object, even classes and types. And later on you might start using objects as "little machines" as Alan Kay called them once and then you got the OOP paradigm right.

I did some crude oversimplifications to keep it as brief as possible, so please do not grill me over it.