# Alternate constructor missing required positional arguments

Tags: python, function, oop

I wrote a function `wczytaj` to get all parameters and I would like to return them to constructor but it doesn't work in this way. I'm wondering why not and how to fix it

I get this error:

```
 TypeError: wczytaj() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'
```

Is it impossible to write one function and return 3 parameters?

```
 from math import sqrt

 def wczytaj(a , b , c):
      a = input("Podaj parametr A? ")
      b = input("Podaj parametr B ")
      c = input("Podaj parametr C? ")
      return a , b , c

 class Rk:

      def __init__(self,a,b,c):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b        
         self.c = c


 nowe = Rk(wczytaj())


 print("Ten program rozwiązuje równanie kwadratowe po podaniu parametrów.")
 print("\n Równianie jest postaci {}x*x + {}x + {} = 0  ".format(a, b, c), end="")
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing it [as you've already been shown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27250497/3001761)? I have removed the request to *"explain me [OOP]"*; that is too broad a question for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the arguments from the `wczytaj` function

```
def wczytaj():
      a = input("Podaj parametr A? ")
      b = input("Podaj parametr B ")
      c = input("Podaj parametr C? ")
      return a , b , c
```

Then you have to use the `*` operator to unpack the returned values as arguments into your class `__init__`

```
nowe = Rk(*wczytaj())
```

You can see now that when I entered `1`, `2`, `3` respectively, the members were now set

```
>>> nowe.a
1
>>> nowe.b
2
>>> nowe.c
3
```